# Issue while receiving a message from service bus queue

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, message-queue, azureservicebus

I have a partitioned service bus queue, based upon the session id I am receiving the message within the queue. But I am getting the following expcetion,

> The requested session '343747143130383837004500' cannot be accepted. It may be locked by another receiver. TrackingId:429fae51-488b-4365-b0aa-06127a47b428_B2, SystemTracker:maxeeservicebus:queue:maxeemessages~255, Timestamp:2021-11-10T06:19:54 TrackingId:1ffb82129f4a44d9a03c2f3a812606e5_G27, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2021-11-10T06:19:54 (SessionCannotBeLocked)content: 3437471431303838370045000000000001

Please assist me to reslove this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some more details about the configurations or any code?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when a message cannot acquire lock on a session while receiving. And while trying to accept a session with specific session id but it is currently locked by other client.

**Resolution**: Based on the error message, check the other clients and make sure sessions are unlocked by them.

Below are few things that should be considered:

- Usually a message which is sent by client or any application to queue can create a session by setting session id property to any value.
- Session Enabled entities can be created from Azure portal by checking the box while creating a queue.
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/media/message-sessions/subscription-sessions.png
- The session enabled Azure Service Bus Queue can be created by setting the ‘RequireSession’ property to true, using **WindowsAzure.ServiceBus** library in .Net client. Below is the sample code:

  ```
    QueueDescription _azureQueue = new QueueDescription("session-enabled-queue")
     {
            RequiresSession = true
      };

    NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(“connectionString”);

    var queue = await namespaceManager.CreateQueueAsync(_azureQueue);
  ```
- Below is the sample code for receiving messages from session enabled Service Bus entities:

  ```
    MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(“connectionString”);
    var queueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient(“queueName”);
    var sessionClient = await queueClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(“sessionId”);
    BrokeredMessage _message = await sessionClient.ReceiveAsync();
    await sessionClient.CloseAsync();
  ```

  Receiving messages without setting ‘SessionId’ using AcceptMessageSessionAsync() will receive the first message in the Queue or Topic Subscription and will initialize the session receiver with the SessionId of that message.
- To send a transactional message to a session enabled Queue or Topic, the message must have the ‘SessionId’ property set. If the ‘PartitionKey’ property is specified as well, it must be identical to the ‘SessionId’ property. If both the ‘Partitionkey’ and ‘SessionId’ differ, then it turns out to be an invalid operation exception.